# Excel Chart - Automatically Adjust Scale of Secondary Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I have 3 pivot charts being controlled by a slicer that changes the week ending date.  On the chart I have "Impressions" on the Primary Axis and "Clicks" on the secondary axis.

What I would like is for the scale of the Secondary axis to automatically adjust when the slicer is changed, so that it is always equal to 2% of the Primary axis.  This way, I know that when the Secondary line is above the Primary line we have hit our target.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there would be an automatic way for that. You probably need to use macros for it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your efforts with the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using VBA and the Worksheet Change function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim x As Long


With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    x = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = (x * 0.02)

End With

End Sub
```